# UrlFetchApp ignoring GET query parameters

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, get, httprequest, urlfetch

I'm running into the following when trying to do a GET request, with Auth, using UrlFetchApp.

Here's what I have:

```
function getAllProducts() { 
  const key = "MY KEY";
  const secret = "MY SECRET";

  const options = {
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(key + ":" + secret),
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache", // This didn't seem to matter
      "Pragma": "no-cache" // This didn't seem to matter either
    }
  };

  const url = 'https://www.my-domain/wp-json/wc/v3/products?per_page=1&page=1'; // Seems to just be ignoring these?!?!?!?
  Logger.log(url); // This logs the correct url with params

  return callAPI(url, options); 
}

function callAPI(url, options) {
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); // After first call I can just remove options and it'll work without Auth?!?!?
  const jsonResponse = response.getContentText();
  const data = JSON.parse(jsonResponse);

  return data;
}
```

In summary:

- I'm getting the response, as if I had passed it no query params at all.
- After running it once, I can even remove the `options` from the `.fetch(url, options)`, and still gives the same response. So it's obviously caching something - but that doesn't explain it ignoring the query params.
- When I try this with the equivalent curl command, it works exactly as expected.
- I can only reproduce this "ignoring params" issue for this, so I am using the WooCommerce API if it helps, but it really shouldn't be, given the curl command works.

Here's the curl for ref:

```
curl https://www.my-domain.co.za/wp-json/wc/v3/products?per_page=1 -u <KEY>:<SECRET>
```

I would love some help here - really pulling my hair out on this one!

Comment: What was the response? And what did you expect?

Comment: Response was exactly what I would get if the query params were not included. I was expecting 1 item, page 1 - and it gave me the default 10 items. Hope that helps!

Comment: Essentially - my overall issue, is that I can't get all the items, because the ```?page=x``` won't work. So I can only get 10 items (page 1). (10 is the default - as if no parameters had been passed). So if I have 16 items - I can only ever get 10.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I send query parameters to other websites, it works. Try sending user-agent header and Accept:*/* headers.

Comment: I also can't reproduce this with normal GETs. It's only for this case, where I'm also using auth - that this problem occurs. It seems to work from curl, as well as python - so I'm probably just going to find a way around the problem and avoid using UrlFetchApp for this.